# Automatically adjust the language of the page when you open it using getX in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

Automatically adjust the language of the page when you open it using getX in flutter, I want to choose the language on a page, and when I choose it, I will move to another page and be in the language I chose

```
Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, right: 20.0),
                child: new Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    new Expanded(
                      child: FlatButton(
                        shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0)),
                        splashColor: this.primaryColor,
                        color: this.primaryColor,
                        child: new Row(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            new Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0),
                              child: Text(
                                "English",
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                              ),
                            ),
                            new Expanded(
                              child: Container(),
                            ),
                            new Transform.translate(
                              offset: Offset(15.0, 0.0),
                              child: new Container(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                                child: FlatButton(
                                  shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                      borderRadius:
                                          new BorderRadius.circular(28.0)),
                                  splashColor: Colors.white,
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  child: Icon(
                                    Icons.arrow_forward,
                                    color: this.primaryColor,
                                  ),
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    box.write('lang', 'en_US');
                                    Get.to(() => LoginScreen1());
                                  },
                                ),
                              ),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                        onPressed: () {
                          box.write('lang', 'en_US');
                          Get.to(() => LoginScreen1());
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
```

the second page

```
Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 40.0),
                  child: Text(
                    'serverAddress'.tr,
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 16.0),
                  ),
                ),
```

There is more than this too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `onPressed` function, we can use the `Get.updateLocale` function accordingly:

```
onPressed: () {
  box.write('lang', 'en_US');
  Locale locale = Locale('en','en_US');
  Get.updateLocale(locale);
  Get.to(() => LoginScreen1());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

GetX Provide a function to change locale language

```
Get.updateLocale(locale);
```

you need to pass locale to change the language. Eg:

```
var locale = Locale('hi','IN');
Get.updateLocale(locale);
```

Comment: I know it but I don't know where to put it

Comment: Just before of `Get.to(() => LoginScreen1());`

Answer (score 0):

We've many solution for this...
U read the documentation about internationalization in flutter ?
https://flutter.dev/docs/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization

This link show a good approch to solution your question.
But I work with getx with another approch...

I've a class with all strings localizations (en,es,pt ...), in my Main.dart I've a getx obs to listen all changes in localization.

See:

Main.dart:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  
  const MyApp({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
   
    return GetX<AppController>(
      builder: (_) =>(
        _buildWithTheme(context,_)
      )
    );
    
  }

  Widget _buildWithTheme(BuildContext context, AppController state) {

    return  MaterialApp(
      title: 'App Title',
      theme:  makeAppTheme(),           
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      initialRoute: '/',
      locale: setLocale(state),      
      navigatorKey: GeneralUtils.globalCtx,
      routes: {
          '/': (context) => const Page1(),
          '/page2': (context) => const Page2(),
      },

    );
  }

  Locale setLocale(AppController state){

    switch (state.pdvLocale) {
      
      case 'en':
        return const Locale('en','US');
      case 'es':
        return const Locale('es','');
      case 'pt':       
      default:
        return const Locale('pt','BR');
    }

  }
```

Page1.dart:

```
Text(AppLocalization.hello)
```

AppLocalization.dart

```
class AppLocalizations{

  static String hellow;

  static setStringsLocation(String localization){

    switch (localization) {
      case 'en':
        hello = 'hello';
        break;
      case 'es':   
        hello = 'hola';
        break;
      case 'pt':
      default:
        hello = 'ola';
    }
  } 
}
```

AppController.dart

```
Future<void> setLocale(String value) async{
    pdvLocale = value;
    await StoreData.instance.saveString('pdv_locale',value); 
    await AppLocalizations.setStringsLocation(pdvLocale);

    update();
}
```

This workaround works perfecttly for me using getx.